# add --host option of configure file (makefile) ,how to do?

Tags: makefile, arm, configure

add --host option of configure file (makefile) ,how to do?

I want to build a library of armv7 and armv7s,but not found host option。

`bash
sh-3.2# ./configure.sh  --help|grep host
sh-3.2#`

http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/discount-2.1.6.tar.bz2
thanks

Answer (score 2):

This project doesn't seem to use classical autotools approach, where you have `configure.ac` file, that creates `configure` file.

So execute `configure.sh` first and then fix `CC` and `AR` in the created `Makefile`:

```
CC=cc -Wno-return-type -Wno-implicit-int -I.
```

to something like this:

```
CC=arm-linux-gcc -Wno-return-type -Wno-implicit-int -I.
```

Now you can invoke `make`.